# Displaying related table field in expression window using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.16.

Is it possible to display the value of the related table field in the expression window (the red rectangle in the image_1)?

More precisely, I need to display the value from the "surveyType" table instead of the identifier 12 in the expressions window.

[image]

Comment: I guess you should add more information to make clear what you have - otherwise it's difficult to help. It's always a good idea to share project + sample data, so people can test without first re-creating an own project that might not match your use case.

Comment: You have two separate layers? Can you join the your `surveyType` layer to the other?

Comment: Or you mean the identifier 12 is from the first column in your table `surveyType` ? AFAIK QGIS likes to use the first column as the identifier (not necessarily the id, that will be `id` or maybe the primary key field).